# Merge arrays inside of array React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,5,6,8],[3,2,1,5,7,9,10,11],[3,5,6,8,2,1,3,4,6]]
```

I want it to become

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,3,5,6,8,3,2,1,5,7,9,10,11,3,5,6,8,2,1,3,4,6]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Would `arr.flat()` not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: [Title of your question on google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Merge+arrays+inside+of+array+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com). The very first result is the duplicate. Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,5,6,8],[3,2,1,5,7,9,10,11],[3,5,6,8,2,1,3,4,6]]
const output = arr.flat();
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Array.flat()` method to merge arrays inside of array.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const arr = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,5,6,8],[3,2,1,5,7,9,10,11],[3,5,6,8,2,1,3,4,6]];
    
    return console.log(arr.flat());
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```